# Select day after date selectring jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am not strong in jQuery, so there is the case.

I have code

```
.datetimepicker({
onSelectDate:function(current_time,$input){
alert(current.dateFormat('d/m/Y')
}
```

Also in the same form i have select of the day element:

```
<select size="1" name="lessonday">
<option value="monday">monday</option>
<option value="tuedsay">tuedsay</option>
</select>
```

So i want day in this form dynamically being selected after date picking. How it can be made?

I use [jQuery Date Time Picker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) plugin for date selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change your <option> value attributes to use the numbers that represent each day (i.e. 0=Sunday, 1=Monday, etc) then you can do this:

HTML:

```
<select size="1" name="lessonday" id="lessonDay">
  <option value="0">sunday</option>
  <option value="1">monday</option>
  <option value="2">tuedsay</option>
  <option value="3">wednesday</option>
  <option value="4">thursday</option>
  <option value="5">friday</option>
  <option value="6">saturday</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
.datetimepicker({
    onSelectDate:function(selectedDateTime,$input){
        $('#lessonDay').val(selectedDateTime.getDay());
    }
});
```

If you cannot change the value attributes on your <option> tags, you'll need an array to map the `.getDay()` value to the name of the day of the week:

HTML:

```
<select size="1" name="lessonday" id="lessonDay">
  <option value="sunday">sunday</option>
  <option value="monday">monday</option>
  <option value="tuedsay">tuedsay</option>
  <option value="wednesday">wednesday</option>
  <option value="thursday">thursday</option>
  <option value="friday">friday</option>
  <option value="saturday">saturday</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var dayOfWeek = new Array(7);
dayOfWeek[0]=  "sunday";
dayOfWeek[1] = "monday";
dayOfWeek[2] = "tuesday";
dayOfWeek[3] = "wednesday";
dayOfWeek[4] = "thursday";
dayOfWeek[5] = "friday";
dayOfWeek[6] = "saturday";

.datetimepicker({
    onSelectDate:function(selectedDateTime,$input){
        $('#lessonDay').val(dayOfWeek[selectedDateTime.getDay()]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Steve, absolutely brilliant idea, thank you. I used second way with mapping, but tested both of your ideas. And both works perfect! :)